# Install using a Logitech Keyboard and mouse with bluetooth dongle?

Tags: installation, 12.10, bluetooth, logitech

I'm trying to install 12.10 on my system, but my mouse and keyboard are not working during installation. I use the Logitech MX5500 Bluetooth mouse+keyboard combo with a Bluetooth dongle.

My keyboard and mouse work in my UEFI bios, and during the Windows 7/8 installation. My keyboard also works in the Ubuntu screen that allows me to set options, install, use the live cd, etc, before boot.

I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to get this dongle working during the installation process so that I can actually install 12.10.

Comment: I face exactly the same problem with the same mouse/keyboard combo. I used a USB mouse to perform the installation and then I was able use the mx5500 with my ASUS P8P67 Deluxe motherboard bluetooth module. Problem: it doesn't work on the login screen and sometimes doesn't work at all... Do you also have a Bluetooth motherboard ?

Answer (score 1):

My USB keyboard and mouse is Logitech as well and it works fine during install of 12.10, try enabling legacy support for usb in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Beach has some info on this, see it here:
http://mikebeach.org/2010/06/27/logitech-devices-on-ubuntu-linux-and-others/